# Centos 7 - Tomcat matter

Tags: java, centos-7, tomcat

I just installed tomcat on to my web server, and i've got a little question to ask. If i create a java servlet into my www directory, will it get executed by tomcat, or do i need to place it in a tomcat specific directory for that?

Answer (score 0):

The default tomcat webapp directory on Centos7 is `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`. The `www` directory (I suspect you mean the `/var/www` directory) is specific to apache2.

This setting might be changed through the tomcat7 configuration files, which are located under `/etc/tomcat7`, though.